# Calculate where type clause from two different tables

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, measures

I haven't written DAX in a while and I'm having a bit of a hard time putting this together and I am hoping someone could throw in a suggestion.

**What I have:**

Qty Table (a lot more months than January):

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| Location |   Date    | LaborQty |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| NY       | 1/3/2017  | 41.024   |
| NY       | 1/4/2017  | 33.836   |
| NY       | 1/5/2017  | 20.431   |
| NY       | 1/6/2017  | 35.544   |
| NY       | 1/7/2017  | 0        |
| NY       | 1/9/2017  | 33.337   |
| NY       | 1/10/2017 | 41.799   |
| NY       | 1/11/2017 | 70.469   |
| NY       | 1/12/2017 | 35.514   |
| NY       | 1/13/2017 | 31.573   |
| NY       | 1/15/2017 | 0        |
| NY       | 1/16/2017 | 22.041   |
| NY       | 1/17/2017 | 30.518   |
| NY       | 1/18/2017 | 47.576   |
| NY       | 1/19/2017 | 29.53    |
| NY       | 1/20/2017 | 18.155   |
| NY       | 1/21/2017 | 0        |
| NY       | 1/23/2017 | 31.284   |
| NY       | 1/24/2017 | 27.695   |
| NY       | 1/25/2017 | 38.907   |
| NY       | 1/26/2017 | 16.289   |
| NY       | 1/27/2017 | 30.976   |
| NY       | 1/28/2017 | 0        |
| NY       | 1/30/2017 | 21.434   |
| NY       | 1/31/2017 | 16.49    |
+----------+-----------+----------+...etc
```

Rates Table:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
| Location | DateFrom  |   DateTo   | MonthFrom | MonthTo | RateType  | Amount |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
| NY       | 1/1/2017  | 6/30/2017  |         1 |       6 | LaborRate | 129.7  |
| NY       | 7/1/2017  | 9/30/2017  |         7 |       9 | LaborRate | 129.8  |
| NY       | 10/1/2017 | 12/31/2017 |        10 |      12 | LaborRate | 129.9  |
| DC       | 1/1/2017  | 6/30/2017  |         1 |       6 | LaborRate | 130.1  |
| DC       | 7/1/2017  | 9/30/2017  |         7 |       9 | LaborRate | 130.5  |
| DC       | 10/1/2017 | 12/31/2017 |        10 |      12 | LaborRate | 130.7  |
+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Desired type of output for the month *(e.g. LaborQty x LaborRate)*:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
| Month | LaborQty | LaborRate |   Result   |
+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
|     1 | 674.22   | 129.74    | 87473.3    |
|     2 | 350      | 129.74    | 45409      |
|     3 | 375      | 129.74    | 48652.5    |
|     4 | 400      | 129.74    | 51896      |
|     5 | 380      | 129.74    | 49301.2    |
|     6 | 500      | 129.74    | 64870      |
|     7 | 550      | 129.76    | 71368      |
|     8 | 600      | 129.76    | 77856      |
|     9 | 675      | 129.76    | 87588      |
|    10 | 700      | 129.98    | 90986      |
|    11 | 780      | 129.98    | 101384.4   |
+-------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

**What I am trying to write:**

A DAX measure that will output amount like the one shown in the result column. If I where to write a linq query for picking the correct rate it will look something like this:

```
LaborRate = db.Rates
            .Where(a => a.DateFrom <= SelectedDate & a.DateTo >= SelectedDate & a.RateType == "LaborRate")
            .Select(a => a.Amount).Sum();
```

I have tried a combination of CALCULATE, SUM, SUMX, FILTER, RELATED but I couldn't get it to work. Any advice would be much appreciated. What would be the simplest approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by doing the following.

1. Add `Month = MONTH(Qty[Date])` as a calculated column to your `Qty` table.
2. Create a `TotalLaborQty` measure in the `Qty` table as `SUM(Qty[LaborQty])`.
3. Define a `LaborRate` measure in the `Rates` table as detailed below.
4. Define a `Result` measure as `[TotalLaborQty] * [LaborRate]`.
5. Set them up in a matrix with `Qty[Location]` and `Qty[Month]` in the rows and the three measures as the values.

---

```
LaborRate =
    VAR SelectedMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(Qty[Month])
    VAR SelectedLocation = SELECTEDVALUE(Qty[Location])
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Rates[Amount]),
            FILTER(ALL(Rates),
                Rates[MonthFrom] <= SelectedMonth &&
                Rates[MonthTo] >= SelectedMonth &&
                Rates[Location] = SelectedLocation))
```

Comment: Alexis, you made my day! I couldn't possible achieve my goal without your help. Your DAX formula is beautifully written and your logic is excellent. Thank you so much!